# Lista de datos. Python

Tags: python

## Listas en Python

He estado estudiando un poco y tengo una duda. Vi un video en donde el tutor pone un ejemplo de una lista:

year=[1950,1951,1952, ...,2100]

Introduce los puntos(...) para dar seguimiento, pero me marca el error de que no es posible y es error de sintaxis...Es posible poder introducir los puntos o es solo un ejemplo de continuidad.
Agradezco su atencion :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esos puntos son figurativos para dar un ejemplo. Un equivalente en código válido sería esto:

```
year = list(range(1050, 2101))
```

El range con dos parámetros manda un iterador desde el argumento1 hasta el argumento2 - 1. Por eso le puse el `2101`.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Saludos!

Comment: Muchisimas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Exacto, esos puntos suspensivos son solo para dar un ejemplo de los elementos que existe en la lista o arreglo. En ese caso se da a entender que hay elementos desde 1950 hasta 2100 sumando uno en uno.

La linea de codigo que te dejo “Genarito” te servira para escribir todos esos elementos en el arreglo, te dejo ademas la forma de como imprimirlos.

```
year = list(range(1050, 2101))
for x in year:
    print year
```

Saludos, espero sea de ayuda.